# Calculate conversion rate with SQL in Hive

Tags: sql, select, hive, hiveql

I`m trying to calculate CR(Conversion Rate) of column name 'action_type'.

The column 'action_type' is allocated to string values as follows...

- 1 : sale
- 2 : click

So, I think the conversion rate is '(SUM(sale) / SUM(click)) * 100".

The values '1'(sale) and '2'(click) are in the same column 'action_type'.

How do I write a sql query in hive?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You would do this using `case` and aggregation:

```
select (sum(case when action_type = 'sale' then 100.0 else 0 end) /
        sum(case when action_type = 'click' then 1.0 end)
       ) as conversion_rate
from t;
```